# logistic regression with dummy regressors

Tags: logistic, categorical-encoding

I'm considering a logistic regression of $Y$ on $X_1,...,X_K$ where $X_1,...,X_K$ are all dummy variables. I'm wondering if the MLE of such a logistic regression is statistically valid since non of $X$ is continuous. If valid, how can I interpet the estimation results?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be valid?

Comment: When $K=2$, $P(Y=1|X_1,X_2)=\Lambda (\beta_1 X_1+\beta_2 X_2)$. If both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are dummy variables, $P(Y=1|X_1,X_2)$ is either of the four probabilities: $P(Y=1|X_1=1,X_2=1)$, $P(Y=1|X_1=1,X_2=0)$, $P(Y=1|X_1=0,X_2=1)$ or $P(Y=1|X_1=0,X_2=0)$. Although the logistic distribution $\Lambda$ is continuous, $P(Y=1|X_1,X_2)$ takes only discrete values. So, I don't see the effect of assuming continuous logistic distribution.

Comment: The analogy with a mean of a continuous variable is useful here. Suppose X has some continuous distribution. The average of X returns a single value. Does that mean the mean is somehow invalid?

Comment: Thanks. Since $Y$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are all binary, we can compute, say, $P(Y=1|X_1=1, X_2=1)$ from raw data by picking up individuals with $(X_1, X_2)=(1,1)$ and obtain the ratio of $Y=1$ from that group. I'm wondering how this simple method is related to logistic or probit regressions. In the linear model with continuous $Y$, the estimated coefficients correspond to difference in means of $Y$. This result is obtained without distributional assumption in the model. However, in the logistic regression, parametric distributional assumption is imposed and estimates should depend on it.

Comment: The literature notes that LR with dummy variables and a binary target is equivalent to linear discriminant analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering if the MLE of such a logistic regression is statistically valid

Yes, its valid.  There is no requirement that the regressors be continuous.

> If valid, how can I interpet the estimation results?

Each coefficient is the log odds ratio.

A covariate vector of all zeros defines the baseline or reference group.  The exponential of the coefficient, $\exp(\beta_j)$ then describes the factor by which the odds of the outcome changes for the group defined by the covariate vector $x$ such that $x_j = 1$ and $x_i =0 \forall i \neq j$.